# Display all tables created after a particular date

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, database-table

I am using Oracle11g for creating database applications. My question is that I have close to 100 different tables in my database and I want to list out all the tables created after a particular date. Is there any way of listing out these tables. Could someone kindly say how to go about getting this simple thing done. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT object_name, owner, created
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type = 'TABLE' 
AND created >= TO_DATE('20120901', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

And thanx Ben :
[all_objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1155.htm#REFRN20146) definition

Comment: and here's the definition of [`all_objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1155.htm#REFRN20146) that I was getting up while you answered :-).

Comment: Might as well add the TO_DATE function.  Example:  SELECT * 
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type = 'TABLE' 
AND created >= to_date('20120901','YYYYMMDD');

Comment: @RMANExpress well that's not the core of the question, but i can change this ;)

Comment: @Ben the all_objects link did help me gain added knowledge...thanks :)